# How to prevent aliasing in SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, alias

I am using SQLAlchemy to extract data from a SQL Server DB into a Pandas Dataframe:

```
q: Query = self._session(db).query(tbl_obj)
return pd.read_sql(
               str(q),
               db.conn()
          )
```

`tbl_obj` is a `SQLAlchemy` Table object that has been autloaded from an existing table in the DB.

My problem is that the query that's being created automatically aliases the column names to '`TABLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME`,' when I just want them to be '`COLUMN_NAME`.'

I figure this is a fairly simple solution, but I haven't figured it out yet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this because I figured it out while I was typing up the question. The problem was that I was calling `str(q)` when I should have been calling `q.statement`

This code works as expected, because the `'statement'` attribute doesn't include the alisaing:

```
q: Query = self._session(db).query(tbl_obj)
return pd.read_sql(
               q.statement,
               db.conn()
          )
```